# error on external js-file

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm about to do my first steps with GMaps API v3.

Unfortunately I get an error not on my js-file but on an external file:

The external file is:
https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_de/mapfiles/api-3/10/19/main.js
(I think de_de has something to do with Germany)

```
error: main.js 28 a is null
```

My code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51, 10); 
  var mapOptions = {zoom: 12,
                    center: latlng, 
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'),
                                mapOptions);
</script>
```

(map-container is set)
I really wonder why I receive an error on this EXTERNAL FILE. Has anyone an answer to that?

Comment: [your code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_jsError.html) works for me (no errors), the error is cause by something outside of the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a result of your script, you supply some argument to the API that is expected to be some kind of object, but is null instead.

I guess the element which should contain the map:

```
document.getElementById('map-container')
```

..is unknown.

You either used a wrong ID or  `google.maps.Map()` has been invoked before the document has finished loading/the element is known.

Initialize the map when the load-event of the document fires or put your script somewhere at the end of the `<body>`(beyond  #map-container).